# How to replace cell value of an entire column with values from another sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to replace data from an entire column with data from another table (on another sheet), based on the cell content.

I'm building a database based on entries of the last 10 years on my office's system and the first column of my table is the ID of the entry. In another sheet, I created a table referencing the product of each ID (ColA = ID, ColB = Product).
I need to create a vba code that replaces every ID from my first table with the product name in ColB from the other table, since there are many IDs and they may repeat many times.

I'm not very used to VBA so I don't know from where to start.

-EDIT-
In a few attempts, I'm trying to use the For Each function. My idea was to create some sort of array for the Col1 in first table and read every cell, comparing with the Col1 of Table2 and, if equal, replacing with the adjacent cell of Table2

```
Private Sub massive_update()

Dim code1 As Range
Dim code2 As Range
Dim prod As Range
code1 = "E3:E122"
code2 = "A2:A37"
prod = "B2:B37"
    For Each Item In code1
        If code1 = code2 Then
            Columns("E").Replace what:=code1, replacement:=code2, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. As this is not a code writing service, you will be hard pushed to get someone to write the code for you. We can help but you have to have made an attempt to resolve your problem. We can then help with any issue. Also, if VBA is not your strong suite then you could try using formula's to achieve this. But again, we can help if you show is what you have done

Comment: Could you give an example of your data and your desired output? It sounds like a simple vlookup or index/match would do the job.

Comment: I could use VLOOKUP, but I'm not inserting each entry at a time, I'm copy pasting the entire raw data in the table 1, so I need a code that massively update the first Col.
Supposing that on my first table there are some entries with the id "400" on Col1, I need to replace all the "400" entries with "Potato", for example. I created a second table containing a Col for code and a Col for the meaning, like "Col1 -> 400, Col2 -> Potato".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for such a delayed feedback. It happens that a simple VLOOKUP solved the problem, no need to VBA, no stress.